# Wikidata getting properties of linked item?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I currently have this query that will grab the description and place of death of J.R.R. Tolkien, but I would like to display the city and country of the place of birth. Currently I get a reference to another wikidata item. How can I resolve properties of a linked item to display what I need?

```
SELECT ?description ?placeOfBirth WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q892 } .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    ?item schema:description ?description.
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
  }
  ?item wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth  .
}
```

Comment: just add another triple pattern or not? I mean, that is the whole principle, add triple patterns that represent edges in the RDF graph. Like  `?placeOfBirth wdt:P17 ?country .`

Comment: also, what is the city of a place of birth?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT ?description ?placeOfBirthLabel ?countryofBirthLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q892 } .
  ?item schema:description ?description .
  FILTER (LANG(?description) = "en")
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?item wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth .
  ?placeOfBirth wdt:P17 ?countryofBirth .
}
```